# Continuity in Metric space

Tags: real-analysis

Let $n$ be fixed element in $(M,d)$ $\forall b \in (M,d)$ consider $f_b: M \rightarrow R$ defined by $f_b(x)=d(b,x)-d(n,x)$. Is $f_b$ bounded and continuous?

Comment: What is $n$ in this definition?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: n is just a fixed value in our metric space. SO far I been trying to play around with the triangle inquality @Zircht

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the triangle inequality we have that $\forall x\in M :$

$$d(b,x)\le d(b,n)+d(n,x)\implies f_b(x)=d(b,x)-d(n,x)\le d(b,n),$$

from where $f_b$ is bounded.

With respect to continuity use that for any $x_0\in M$ the function $d(x,x_0)$ is continuous. Thus, $f_b$ is continuous since it is the difference of two continuous functions.